# TypeError: g is not a function

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

While re-writing one of my applications from scratch (to go from legacy to AMD) I'm encountering an error which I can't figure out. It is driving me crazy. I'm probably just misspelling something or have another minor mistake, but I just can't figure out what. Any help would be highly appreciated!

I'm still in development mode, so my code isn't that pretty at this time. You can see it live in action at here: http://tpgrf.nl/testserver/alpha/topotrainer/flevoland

The javascript code:

```
//Define area and url's  
var currentPath = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var AREA = currentPath[currentPath.length - 2];
if (AREA == 'europa' || AREA == 'wereld' || AREA == 'nederland') {
    var AREAURL = AREA;
    var AREAisProvince = false;
} else {
    AREAURL = 'nederland';
    var AREAisProvince = true;
}; //Ondervang provincies  


var basemapURL = window.location.protocol + "//tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/arcgis/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_" + AREAURL + "_ondergrond/MapServer";
var contentFeatureURL = window.location.protocol + "//services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_" + AREAURL + "/FeatureServer/0";




var CONTENT = 'cito100'; //Default to 'cito100', user can adjust manually  
var TYPES = ''; //empty for now, will be defined later by the user  
var TYPES = 'plaats'; //for testingunction's//  
//  
function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};


//  
//Figure something out here to detect if the user as a new or returning visitor  
//  


//////////////////////////////////////  
//Create a basemap and load features//  
//////////////////////////////////////  
var dojoConfig = { parseOnLoad: true };


var map;
require(["esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/map", "esri/graphic", "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/FeatureSet", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", "esri/Color", "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer", "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",
    "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on"],
    function (Extent, SpatialReference, Map, Graphic, Tiled, Query, QueryTask, FeatureSet, GraphicsLayer, Color, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, PictureMarkerSymbol, UniqueValueRenderer, ClassBreaksRenderer, dom, on) {
        //@TODO: Can we actually define this on the basemap mapserver?  
        if (AREA == 'nederland' || AREAisProvince == true) {
            var initExtent = new Extent(-165715, 6453119, 1435181, 7205260, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 }));
        }
        if (AREA == 'europa') {
            var initExtent = new Extent(-2827847, 2851709, 6838658, 11375669, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 }));
        }
        if (AREA == 'wereld') {
            var initExtent = new Extent(-19705424, -14849545, 21700207, 21624981, new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 }));
        }

        map = new Map("map", {
            extent: initExtent
        });


        //let's add a basemap  
        var tiled = new Tiled(basemapURL);
        map.addLayer(tiled);

        where = 'Cito100_onderdeel=1';
        if (AREAisProvince == true) {
            where += ' AND Provincie=\'' + AREA + '\'';
        }
        map.on("load", getFeaturesToMapAndStorage(where));

        function getFeaturesToMapAndStorage(whereClause) {
            console.log(whereClause);
            //query the featureService  
            var query = new Query();
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = ["*"];
            query.outSpatialReference = new SpatialReference({ wkid: 102100 });
            query.where = whereClause;

            var queryTask = new QueryTask(contentFeatureURL);

            queryTask.on("complete", function (event) {
                //map.graphics.clear();  
                var featureGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();


                //@TODO: Can't we find a way to use the symbols from the featurservice directly, instead of the url's?  
                defaultSymbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new Color([255, 0, 0]), 1),
            new Color([0, 255, 0, 0.25]));

                var renderer = new UniqueValueRenderer(defaultSymbol, "Type");
                renderer.addValue("Plaats", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0/images/89e5f81878a69f9cc0525c841f98af54", 11, 11));
                renderer.addValue("Gebied", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0/images/165c76bd4465728a34f6d18df4a1ec03", 28, 28));
                renderer.addValue("Water", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0/images/f9c146a401f48c4f38202e83c2e4582a", 22, 22));
                renderer.addValue("Provincie", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_nederland/FeatureServer/0/images/7a5373d8f1dcd1ecc03cefbab687b97c", 38, 32));
                renderer.addValue("Land", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_europa/FeatureServer/0/images/7a5373d8f1dcd1ecc03cefbab687b97c", 38, 32));
                renderer.addValue("Werelddeel", new PictureMarkerSymbol("https://services.arcgis.com/nSZVuSZjHpEZZbRo/ArcGIS/rest/services/Topografie_in_de_klas_wereld/FeatureServer/0/images/48f2256a49253388488d813d721c054b", 32, 38));

                var features = event.featureSet.features;
                var featureCount = features.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < featureCount; i++) {
                    var graphic = features[i];
                    featureGraphicsLayer.add(graphic);
                }
                featureGraphicsLayer.renderer = renderer;
                map.addLayer(featureGraphicsLayer);

                //@TODO: Update localstorage    

            }); //end on queryTask complete  

            queryTask.execute(query, queryComplete);

            function queryComplete() {
                console.log("fire function queryComplete");
                //@TODO: reset progressbar  
            }; //End function queryComplete  


        } //end function getFeaturesToMapAndStorage  

        //The two closing tags below are essential and close the complete DOJO part.    
    } //end function after require (AMD style)  
    ); //end require
```

Comment: You didn't add the link to live demo.

Comment: or tell us what line is giving you the error :(

Comment: @RyanKempt His error's most likely in some minified event code (hence `g`). See my answer below.

Comment: Just added the link, sorry for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with: `map.on("load", getFeaturesToMapAndStorage(where));`

You're calling `getFeaturesToMapAndStorage` which returns undefined, and passing that in as the `"load"` handler. I'm guessing that the minified version of whatever it is that you're using uses `g` as a reference to your handler.

Since `g` is undefined, you're basically saying `undefined(loadEvent)`.

---

EDIT: I'm guessing you meant to do something like this:

```
map.on("load", function(){
    getFeaturesToMapAndStorage(where);
});
```

EDIT 2: For clarity, I'll explain what was wrong in more detail.
The difference between what you had and what I suggested above, is that you were calling `getFeaturesToMapAndStorage` on the line containing `map.on("load", getFeaturesToMapAndStorage(where));` (as opposed to calling it after `map`'s `load` event). In order to call your function `getFeaturesToMapAndStorage` with a predetermined parameter, you need to call it from a function (like the anonymous function above - `function(){...}`) that would then be passed in as the event handler.

Alternatively, due to how you have things scoped, you could reference your `where` inside of `getFeaturesToMapAndStorage` in place of having a `whereClause` parameter.

Comment: I just tested. It seems to have worked. Is this the expected result? http://imgur.com/tQ5V0mF

Comment: I will be able to implement your suggestion in a couple of hours when back home. But the result should be similar to https://topografieindeklas.nl/topotrainer/provincies/flevoland/ , which looks different then your example (your examples has only the basemap, not the features drawn as a graphics layer)

Comment: @DennisHunink, that appears to be an issue beyond this type error. To debugm the svg layer emptying, we'd probably want to be stepping through unminified versions of the map/svg libs.

Comment: You're awesome sir, this indeed did the trick. Thanks for explaining it in a lot more detail, that really makes sense to me. Awsome!

Comment: Happy to help! Good luck with the project :D